# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_manage'

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have encountered an issue related to the running of django-cms.

1. I downloaded a zip package of djangoCMS sourcecode from https://www.django-cms.org/en/.
2. I extracted zip file to a location on my hdd.
3. I set up my virtual env for my folder I've just extracted on hdd already
4. When I run command "python manage.py runserver", I have encountered an error like the tile of this post.
   "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_manage'"

Comment: What is `app_manage`? Is it in your project somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you didn't have Django installed but that still wouldn't work because Django CMS is not really supposed to be ran stand alone like that, it's normally the dependency of a Django project like any other Django app.

To create a project for the CMS you should follow this tutorial: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/01-install.html

I recommend reading and creating a separate Django project without Django CMS to help understand what a Django project requires, you can follow this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/